# Solve trigonometric system of equations

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, systems-of-equations

I have a seemingly simple system of equations, but I don’t know how to solve this.

$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
\cos(x) \cos(y) &=0 \\ 
- \sin(x) \sin(y) &=0 \\
\end{array} 
\right.
$$

Is there any trick?

Comment: Hint : $\cos(x)$ and $\sin(x)$ cannot be both $0$, same for $\cos(y)$ and $\sin(y)$. So which combinations remain to get both expressions $0$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\cos{x}=0$ then since, $\sin{x}\neq0$, we get $\sin{y}=0$ and
$$\left\{\left(\frac{\pi}{2}+\pi k,\pi m\right)|\{k,m\}\subset\mathbb Z\right\}.$$

The case $\cos{y}=0$ for you.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that we could set the equations equal $$ \cos(x)\cos(y) + \sin(x)\sin(y) = 0,$$ and using a trig identity, we get
$$ \cos(x-y) = 0.$$
Then we know where the zeros of the cosine function are, namely when $$x-y = \frac{(2n+1)\pi}{2}, \; n \in \mathbb{Z}.$$

Comment: And from there how do I get separate solutions for x and y?